# how to fetch data according to slug in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch the particular blog according to the slug but I'm getting a axios error of 404 not found. i would really appreciate if any one can help..

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const data = "https://bulkaccounts.com/api/blogs";
function Singleblog() {
  const { slug } = useParams();
  const [blog, setBlog] = useState({});
  const [isloading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBlogBySlug = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/blog/${slug}`);
        console.log({ res });
        if (res?.data?.data) {
          setBlog(res.data.data);
        } else {
          setError("Blog not found.");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setError("Blog not found.");
      }

      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchBlogBySlug();
  }, [slug]);

  let showData = "";
   showData = (
    <>
       <div className="blog">
        {data &&
          data.datas.data.map((item) => {
             return (
              <>
                <div className="flex-container">
                   <div className="card">hello</div>
                 </div>
              </>
             );
           })}
       </div>
     </>
   );

  return (
    <>
 {showData}
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </>
  );
}

export default Singleblog;
```

// Api = https://bulkaccounts.com/api/blogs

i tried that code but it doesn't worked for me. help me figure out my mistake

Comment: When you are in that component, the one you shared, what is the url?

Answer (score 0):

First, check if http://localhost:3000/blog is a valid back-end server URL.

I think replacing http://localhost:3000/blog with https://bulkaccounts.com/api/blogs will solve the problem.

Comment: i tried but didn't worked for me :(

Comment: Hello sheikh 'I think' is not a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou very much for help. I got my answer, actually i was making a silly mistake. I've store data in "blog", but down in code i was trying to map "data".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).